# initialize numpy array with named tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, initialization, namedtuple

I'm trying to initialize a NumPy array that contains named tuples. Everything works fine when I initialize the array with `empty` data and set that data afterwards; when using the `numpy.array` constructor, however, NumPy doesn't do what I had expected.

The output of

```
import numpy

data = numpy.random.rand(10, 3)
print data[0]

# Works
a = numpy.empty(
    len(data),
    dtype=numpy.dtype([('nodes', (float, 3))])
    )
a['nodes'] = data
print
print a[0]['nodes']


# Doesn't work
b = numpy.array(
    data,
    dtype=numpy.dtype([('nodes', (float, 3))])
    )
print
print b[0]['nodes']
```

is

```
[ 0.28711363  0.89643579  0.82386232]

[ 0.28711363  0.89643579  0.82386232]

[[ 0.28711363  0.28711363  0.28711363]
 [ 0.89643579  0.89643579  0.89643579]
 [ 0.82386232  0.82386232  0.82386232]]
```

This is with NumPy 1.8.1.

Any hints on how to organize the `array` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

This is awful, but:

Starting with your example copied and pasted into an ipython, try

```
dtype=numpy.dtype([('nodes', (float, 3))])
c = numpy.array([(aa,) for aa in data], dtype=dtype)
```

it seems to do the trick.

Comment: That said, I think the option using `empty` also reads the data in as an iterator. So it is maybe not much better. The main question is qhy one would want to do this if one could also not do it.

Comment: The basic point is that with a `dtype` like this, the array elements are `tuples`.  `a[1]` returns a `tuple`.  So to set the whole array, you have to use a list of tuples.  `a[:]=[(x,) for x in data]` also works.

Comment: yes, that is the OPs first option. And it is stated as working - even if the data array is maybe read in as an iterator (not 100% sure). so in that case converting to tuples is not even necessary. The question is about how to use the numpy array constructor to du the same thing

Answer (score -1):

It's instructive to construct a different array:

```
dt3=np.dtype([('x','<f8'),('y','<f8'),('z','<f8')])
b=np.zeros((10,),dtype=dt3)
b[:]=[tuple(x) for x in data]
b['x'] = data[:,0]  # alt
np.array([tuple(x) for x in data],dtype=dt3) # or in one statement

a[:1] 
# array([([0.32726803375966484, 0.5845638956708634, 0.894278688117277],)], dtype=[('nodes', '<f8', (3,))])
b[:1]
# array([(0.32726803375966484, 0.5845638956708634, 0.894278688117277)], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

I don't think there's a way of assigning `data` to all the fields of `b` without some sort of iteration.

---

`genfromtxt` is a common way of generating record arrays like this.  Looking at its code I see a pattern like:

```
data = list(zip(*[...]))
output = np.array(data, dtype)
```

Which inspired me to try:

```
dtype=numpy.dtype([('nodes', (float, 3))])
a = np.array(zip(data), dtype=dtype)
```

(speed's basically the same as eickenberg's comprehension; so it's doing the same pure Python list operations.)

And for the 3 fields:

```
np.array(zip(*data.T), dtype=dt3)
```

curiously, explicitly converting to list first is even faster (almost 2x the `zip(data)` calc)

```
np.array(zip(*data.T.tolist()), dtype=dt3)
```

Comment: In that case it is probably interesting to do the whole thing as a `recarray`

Comment: `zip(data)` makes a more compact expression.